# Let $A$ be a $4 \times 3$ matrix where none of the rows is entirely zero. Which of the following statements is/are definitely true?

Tags: linear-algebra

(I) It is possible that the rows of $A$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(II) It is possible that the columns of $A$ forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$.

(III) It is possible that $Ax=0$ has only the trivial solution.

Just want to check am I right to say only (III) is true?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the rows can't form a basis since a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has exactly $3$ elements. Similarly for the column, since a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ has exactly $4$ elements.

To have exactly the trivial solution, just let $A = \begin{bmatrix}I_3 \\ b^T \end{bmatrix}$ where $b$ is non-zero. Then the system only has the trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the rows are all zero, you can get a matrix like below:

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 & 0   \\
    0       & 1 & 0  \\
    0       & 0 & 1   \\
    0       & 0 & 1   \\
\end{bmatrix}

That is a matrix with rank 3.  Clearly the three columns are independent. Thus no $[x1 \ x2 \ x3]^T$ with non-zero entries can multiply it so that result is 0. So, yes, it is possible to get a Matrix where $Ax=0$ has only trivial solution.

But that does not mean this will be the case always.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 1 & 0   \\
    1       & 1 & 0  \\
    1       & 1 & 0   \\
    1       & 1 & 0   \\
\end{bmatrix}

This Matrix has rank 1. And it is easy to find non-zero solution for it.

Comment: Both of these matrices have a row that is entirely zero.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.